# Is this definition of Cartesian Products of Families correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

I was wondering if the way I defined the Cartesian Product of Families correct. Now, I am more inclined to predicate logic notation so if there may be any notational discrepancies, you must excuse me.

∏<sub>i ∈ I</sub>X<sub>i</sub> = {*f*(i) : *f* ∈ (⋃<sub>i ∈ I</sub>X<sub>i</sub>)<sup>I</sup> ∧ ∀*f*(i)[*f*(i) ∈ X<sub>i</sub>]}

Answer (score 0):

No. The quantifier $\forall f(i)$ does not make sense. You can only quantify over variables. Furthermore, the set contains the actual function $f$, not merely its value at a particular $i$. So the correct definition would be

$$\prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i = \{f \in (\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} X_i)^I \mid \forall i \in I (f(i) \in X_i)\}$$

Comment: but f(i) is considered a complex variable. Is it not? And moreover, I have seen the way you defined it previously, but could not understand how that yields the desired result. For we don't need the set of all those functions themselves, but rather the set containing the range of each function as an n-tuple. So if I correct my definition, wouldn't it be ∏<sub> i ∈ I </sub> Xi = {ordered pairs f(i) : f ∈ (⋃ i ∈ I Xi)**superscript**I  ∧ ∀i ∈ I(f(i) ∈ X)}. Also, how do you do math symbols?

Comment: @Camelot823 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Camelot823 $f(i)$ is not a variable. Both $f$ and $i$ are variables; $f(i)$ is an expression which contains both. I’m not sure what you mean by $n$-tuple. What is $n$ in this context? But at any rate, we clearly care about more than just the range of $f$ - it matters what value each $i$ corresponds to. So we do want the whole function.

Comment: @Camelot823 The set $\prod\limits_{i \in \{0, 1\}} X_i$ is not actually *equal* to the set $X_0 \times X_1$ in most cases. There is, however, a canonical bijection between the two. For defining the product of an $I$-indexed family, we need a definition which works with any index set. The definition I gave in my answer achieves this. You could imagine coming up with any 2-element set $J = \{a, b\}$ and taking the product $\prod\limits_{i \in J} X_i$. How would I make this set equal to $X_0 \times X_1$ if I have no way of knowing whether $a$ or $b$ should be the first index?

Comment: Ahh, this is exactly what I was searching for. I HAVE conceived a method for recovering ordered pairs from all those functions. Although I haven't heard the term "canonical bijection" before, I assume that you are referring to THAT method for recovering ordered n-tuples from those functions. Am I correct?

Comment: @Camelot823 When I talk about “canonical bijections”, I’m saying that we can define, for any sets $X_0, X_1$, a bijection $g : \prod\limits_{i \in \{0, 1\}} X_i \to X_0 \times X_1$ by $g(f) = (f(0), f(1))$. So for practical purposes, the two sets are “the same”, although they are typically not equal. You can generalise this to products over $I = \{0, \ldots, n - 1\}$ if you have a predefined notion of an $n$-tuple. “Canonical” is a bit of a funny word; in this case, when I talk about the “canonical bijection”, I’m referring to the specific $g$ I defined above.

Comment: thank you much! This conversation really helped me a lot. Just to be clear, when I define a cartesian product over some family, say the two member family $\{A_0,A_1\}$, would the cartesian product generally imply $A_0 \times A_1$, or would I have to mandatorily specify the "canonical bijection" for it to do so?